# Need help reading XML using LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to bind the contents of the following file using LINQ but having issues with the syntax.

```
<metadefinition>
  <page>
    <name>home</name>
    <metas>
      <meta>
        <metaname>
          title
        </metaname>
        <metavalue>
          Welcome Home
        </metavalue>
      </meta>

      <meta>
        <metaname>
          description
        </metaname>
        <metavalue>
          Welcome Home Description
        </metavalue>
      </meta>

    </metas>
  </page>

  <page>
    <name>results</name>
    <metas>
      <meta>
        <metaname>
          title
        </metaname>
        <metavalue>
          Welcome to Results
        </metavalue>
      </meta>
    </metas>
  </page>
</metadefinition>
```

My query looks like this but as you can see it is missing the retrieval of the metas tag. How do I accomplish this?

```
 var pages = from p in xmlDoc.Descendants(XName.Get("page"))
                            where p.Element("name").Value == pageName
                            select new MetaPage
                            {
                                Name = p.Element("name").Value,
                                MetaTags = p.Elements("metas").Select(m => new Tag { MetaName = m.Element("metaname").Value.ToString(),
                                                                                     MetaValue = m.Element("metacontent").Value.ToString()
                                }).ToList()
                            };
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what exactly you are trying to accomplish here. What do you mean by "*it is missing the retrieval of the metas tag*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `<metadefinition>` is a root element, then there is no need for iterating over all descendants of the document, that's way too inefficient.

```
var pages = from p in xmlDoc.Root.Elements("page")
            where p.Element("name").Value == pageName
            select new MetaPage {
                Name = p.Element("name").Value,
                MetaTags = p.Element("metas").Elements("meta").Select(m=>new Tag{
                    MetaName = m.Element("metaname").Value.ToString(),
                    MetaValue = m.Element("metavalue").Value.ToString()
                }).ToList()
            };
```